# Show that the graph of the function $z(x,y) = x\tan(y)$ is a minimal surface

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, minimal-surfaces

> Show that the graph of the function $z(x,y) = x\tan(y)$ is a minimal surface

I'm really lost on how to do this question. I know we have to use the Euler equation to show this, but other than that I'm a bit lost because it's two different variables without a constraint.

Comment: The graph $z=f(x,y)$ is a minimal surface iff it satisfies [a certain PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface#History), so it's just a matter of plugging things in and simplifying a lot.